# Docker containers not listed

Tags: docker, portainer

I am pretty new to Docker/Portainer, and try to get to understand the basics.

I have several Containers running (i can access them), which are not listed with "docker ps -a", for example a Drupal-container on http://0.0.0.0:8081/

I do see it on my Linux:
root@plan:/home/andre# ps -aux | grep docker | grep 8081
root        1212  0.0  0.0 549052  3932 ?        Sl   16:44   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8081 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 80

But "docker ps -a" does not list me the above container. I can't even  find it's image with "docker images".

A restart of my Ubuntu session did not change anything.

Comment: Can you please exhibit the outcomes so that it helps better in understanding ?
Also, what's the docker version and the base system ?

Comment: @DhakkanCoder: The base System is Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest Docker and Portainer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I have two versions of Docker installed, the following screenshots explains the problem:

[image]